# Get error, When I create view to read Foxpro DBF file for manage table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, visual-foxpro

I try to read Foxpro DBF files with Microsoft SQL Server 2012
i use this query

```
CREATE VIEW DBF_out
AS
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('MSDASQL','Driver=Microsoft Visual FoxPro Driver;SourceDB=C:\Data;SourceType=DBF','SELECT * FROM out')
```

Then i get error below

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "(null)" returned message
>   "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no
>   default driver specified". Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Procedure
>   DBF_out, Line 3 Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB
>   provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "(null)".

Previously i execute this

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options' 1  reconfigure go

sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries',1 RECONFIGURE
```

how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have to enclose driver name in curly brackets, like this:

```
Driver={Microsoft Visual FoxPro Driver}
```

Source: [connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-visual-foxpro-odbc-driver/)

This driver may not work in 64bit environments however.

Comment: i use win7 64bit  
What should I do to solve this issue?
Have other ways?